# Automatic log group creation in AWS cloudwatch using fluent bit in EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-eks, fluent-bit

Is there a way to automatically ship the logs from EKS pods to cloudwatch using fluent bit whenever new pods come up ?
I am able to send the logs by adding INPUT, FILTER, OUTPUT section in fluent-bit configmap whenever we need to deploy a new service. But this process is cumbersome. Is there a way to automate this part ? like when we do a new deployment , fluent bit sees the new pods and ships the log to specific log group in cloudwatch.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your fluent-bit not running as daemonset?

Comment: yes , it is running as a daemon set. But I dont see the new pod's log getting shipped until I put the INPUT and OUTPUT section. I have a feeling that , there is something missing in my config.

Comment: Your logs write to stdout or custom location on the host?

Comment: I have both . Few service writes log in stdout and few writes log to custom locations. Those custom locations anyway have mounted in the flunetbit daemon set .

Comment: Here  is the config file for flunet-bit I am using. https://github.com/satyaki88/fluent-bit/blob/main/fluent-bit.yaml

Answer (score 2):

Digging into the documentation here is the solution, there are two cloud watch output plugins mainly used and both of them supports what is called **log group templating**:

For example if your aggregated logs will be in this form:

```
{
  "kubernetes": {
      "container_name": "sample-api"
      "namespace_name": "sample-namespace",
      "pod_name": "sample-api-597d7449b5-wbcmq"
  },
  "log": "sample logs \n"
}
```

1. `cloudwatch` created by aws (most probably if you deployed fluentbit following aws documentation)

```
  [OUTPUT]
        Name                cloudwatch
        Match               application.*
        region              ${AWS_REGION}
        log_group_name      /aws/myKubeCluster/$(kubernetes['container_name'])
        log_stream_name     $(kubernetes['container_name']).$(kubernetes['container_name'])
        auto_create_group   true
        extra_user_agent    container-insights
```

2. `cloudwatch_logs` which is the new plugin that is provided by fluentBit and exist in their official documentation

```
  [OUTPUT]
        Name                cloudwatch_logs
        Match               application.*
        region              ${AWS_REGION}
        log_group_name      fallback_group
        log_stream_name     fallback_stream_name
        log_group_template  /aws/myKubeCluster/$kubernetes['container_name']
        auto_create_group   true
        extra_user_agent    container-insights
```

- The difference is that, log_group_template is separate field and in the way that you call your vars (record_accessor)

**Resources:**

- [aws cloudwatch plugin](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-logs-for-fluent-bit#templating-log-group-and-stream-names)
- [fluentBit cloudwatch_logs plugin](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/outputs/cloudwatch#log-stream-and-group-name-templating-using-record_accessor-syntax)

Answer (score 0):

Your input paths have specific expression that capture only certain logs:

> /var/log/containers/*grafana*.log
>
> /var/log/containers/*memsql*.log,/var/log/containers/*studio*.log

No custom location seen in your config. Anyway, you can follow EKS container insights (with fluent-bit) [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Container-Insights-setup-logs-FluentBit.html) which you do not need to change your config every time a new workload is introduced.

Comment: by default all the logs will go in /aws/containerinsights/Cluster_Name/application . But I need new workload's log will create a separate  Log-group. How can we achieve this , without adding the OUTPUT section in the configmap ?